# Singular measure with respect to Lebesgue measure

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, singular-measures

Let $\mu$ be a finite positive Borel measure on $\mathbb{T}$ such that $\mu$ is singular with respect to Lebesgue measure. Let $E$ be a closed subset of $\mathbb{T}$ such that $\mu(\{x\})=0$ for every $x\in E$. Prove or disprove the following:

$\mu(E)=0$.

Comment: It does not. Now, what are your thoughts on this problem?

Comment: I mean I looking for a counter example.

Comment: OK. And? $ $ $ $

Comment: What is $\mathbb{T}$ here?  The torus?  And by the way: @Did is asking you what your thoughts related to finding a counterexample might be.  Show us where you're getting stuck!

Comment: ((Note that "It does not" in my first comment refers to a former version of the question, asking "Does this imply that μ(E)=0 ?"))

Comment: $\mathbb{T}$ represents the circle in plane. I'm stuck in a problem where I would very much like to infer that the above is true but just have no idea how to prove or disprove the above.

Comment: You'll have to consider all examples of singular measures. What's the nastiest singular measure you can think of? (Clearly you won't get by [countable] sums of delta's that are supported at a single point)

Comment: Thanks Evan for your advice, now I think we (my friends) found such a nasty measure:). Do check the answer, it seems it will work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I discussed with some of my friends. So here is an answer:

Consider $[0,1]$ and let $E$ denote the Cantor set. Consider the $\frac{\log2}{\log3}$ dimensional Hausdorff measure on $E.$

Fact: $H(E)=1$ and it is zero on any singleton subset of $E$.

So now we define a measure $\mu$ on $[0,1]$ by $\mu(A)=H(A\cap E),$ then $\mu$ is a finite Borel measure, singular with respect to Lebesgue measure such that $\mu(E)=1$ and $\mu(\{x\})=0$ for every $x\in E.$